# Is it possible to use queryset in the FROM clause

Tags: python, django, orm

I have a model for user's points collection:

```
class Rating(models.Model):
    user = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE, related_name='rating')
    points = models.IntegerField()
```

Each user could have multiple records in this model. I need to calculate a rank of each user by sum of collected points. For the listing it's easy:

```
Rating.objects.values('user__username').annotate(
    total_points=Sum('points')
).order_by('-total_points')
```

But how to get rank for a single user by his user_id? I added annotation with numbers of rows:

```
Rating.objects.values('user__username').annotate(
    total_points=Sum('points')
).annotate(
    rank=Window(
        expression=RowNumber(),
        order_by=[F('total_points').desc()]
    )
)
```

it really added correct ranking numbers, but when I try to get a single user by user_id it returns a row with rank=1. It's because the filter condition goes to the WHERE clause and there is a single row with the number 1. I mean this:

```
Rating.objects.values('user__username').annotate(
    total_points=Sum('points')
).annotate(
    rank=Window(
        expression=RowNumber(),
        order_by=[F('total_points').desc()]
    )
).filter(user_id=1)
```

I got the SQL query of this queryset (qs.query) like

```
SELECT ... FROM rating_rating WHERE ...
```

and inserted it into another SQL query as "rank_table" and added a condition into the outside WHERE clause:

```
SELECT * FROM (SELECT ... FROM rating_rating WHERE ...) AS rank_table WHERE user_id = 1;
```

and executed within the MySQL console. And this works exactly as I need. The question is: how to implement the same using Django ORM?

Answer (score 0):

I have one solution to get what I need. I could add another field to mark records as "correct" or "incorrect" user, sort result by this field and then get the first row:

```
qs.annotate(
    required_user=Case(
        When(user_id=1, then=1),
        default=0,
        output_field=IntegerField(),
    )
).order_by('-required_user').first()
```

This works. But SELECT within another SELECT seems more elegant and I would like to know is it possible with Django.

Answer (score 0):

somehow someone just recently asked something about filtering on windows functions. While what you want is basically [subquery](https://code.djangoproject.com/ticket/28333) (select in select), using annotation with the window function is not supported :
https://code.djangoproject.com/ticket/28333 because the annotated fields will inside the subquery :'(. One provides raw sql with query_with_params, but it is not really elegant.